# Number input spin box CSS code compiler to JSS

Tags: javascript, css, jss

I've got problem with converting **CSS** code for hiding spin box of number input for **JSS**. My question is how to appropriately convert this code that it will match JSS?

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
input[type=number] {
-moz-appearance:textfield; 
}
```

Comment: it is not needed cuz the problem is only in syntax, which I dont know. JSS compiler works only in one way: from JSS to CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
input: {
    '&::-webkit-outer-spin-button, &::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
      '-webkit-appearance': 'none',
      '-moz-appearance': 'none',
      'margin': 0
    },
    '&[type=number]': {
      '-webkit-appearance': 'textfield',
      '-moz-appearance': 'textfield'
    }
  }
```

This should work.

Comment: it worked fine except that 'margin': 0 should be without apostrophes

Comment: do you know what add to this to let it work on Safari. The spinbuttons ale hidden now on Chrome and Firefox except Safari

Comment: It works in Safari. which version of Safari has this issue

Comment: The version of Safari - 12.0.3 (14606.4.5). Nevertheless, to`'webkit-appearance" 'none'`, I have added `!important` and now it works fine.